# Need to separate '&' delimited data into csv file

Tags: python, python-3.6

My data in the text file is in the form of `ÿ{device_id=0BD776ED&temp=24.40&hum=65.19&vcc=3853&packet_no=4&sleep_time=3}` or `þ{device_id=0BD776ED&temp=24.15&hum=65.27&vcc=3853&packet_no=6&sleep_time=3}`
or `ü{device_id=0BD776ED&temp=23.81&hum=61.76&vcc=3827&packet_no=45&sleep_time=3}`

where "ÿ" and "þ" and "ü" are noises that need to be discarded. Sometimes the data coming from the server in the text file is also without any noises like `{device_id=0BD776ED&temp=22.46&hum=61.62&vcc=3840&packet_no=38&sleep_time=3}`

I need to convert this data in the text file into a csv file with the columns device_id, tem, hum, vcc, packet_no and sleep_time.
i started off with writing a code to remove the noise and the brackets but i need to implement an if and else condition in the code
it should be something like:

```
if(y = string.strip('ÿ{')=true then
 c = y.strip('}')
 print(c))
elif(b = string.strip('þ{'))=true then
 c = b.strip('}')
 print(c))
elif(u = string.strip('ü{'))=true then
 c = u.strip('}')
 print(c))
```

Obviously the code above is what i want to write but i don't know the syntax for it since I am a beginner and I am also very well aware that the code above is wrong. The code below needs to be integrated in the form i have explained above. I also need to convert that text file into a csv file. If someone can help me out with either of the two problems it would be great!

```
string ="ÿ{device_id=0BD776ED&temp=24.40&hum=65.19&vcc=3853&packet_no=4&sleep_time=3}"

y = string.strip('ÿ{')
b = string.strip('þ{')
u = string.strip('ü{')
c = y.strip('}')
c = b.strip('}')
c = u.strip('}')
print(c)
```

I made the change that you suggested and this is a small snippet of my data:
[this is a small art of my data whereas the actual data is around 200-2500 lines long](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vZvu.png)

the error that i am getting once i run the code is:
[this is the picture of the code alongside with the image of the error invoked when i run the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FbM5.png)

Comment: Please post code, not images of code.

Comment: This thread is closed thank you for replying to it.

Comment: The fact that you got an answer doesn't detract from the fact that you need to not post images of code.

Comment: Alright. Thank you very very much for your suggestion. I will take care in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleaning up your data is very simple if you are sure you know *exactly* what all the noise will be. You don't need to strip it separately.

```
rows = []
with open('data.txt') as data:
    for line in data:
        columns = line.strip("{}ÿþü ").split("&")
        rows.append(columns)
```

Now your data looks like this:

```
[
['device_id=0BD776ED', 'temp=24.40', 'hum=65.19', 'vcc=3853', 'packet_no=4', 'sleep_time=3'], 
['device_id=0BD776ED', 'temp=24.15', 'hum=65.27', 'vcc=3853', 'packet_no=6', 'sleep_time=3'], 
['device_id=0BD776ED', 'temp=23.81', 'hum=61.76', 'vcc=3827', 'packet_no=45', 'sleep_time=3']
]
```

The next task is to treat `device_id=` as a column label instead of part of the data.

```
dictrows = []
for row in rows:
    dictrows.append(dict(c.split("=") for c in row))
```

Now your data looks like this:

```
[
{'vcc': '3853', 'temp': '24.40', 'hum': '65.19', 'packet_no': '4', 'sleep_time': '3', 'device_id': '0BD776ED'}, 
{'vcc': '3853', 'temp': '24.15', 'hum': '65.27', 'packet_no': '6', 'sleep_time': '3', 'device_id': '0BD776ED'}, 
{'vcc': '3827', 'temp': '23.81', 'hum': '61.76', 'packet_no': '45', 'sleep_time': '3', 'device_id': '0BD776ED'}
]
```

The reason for going to all this trouble to get dicts is because the `csv` module has a `DictWriter` class that accepts dicts as rows.

```
with open('mydata.csv','w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile,["vcc","device_id","temp","hum","packet_no","sleep_time"])  
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in dictrows:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: The sleep_time is not showing in the excel file. The output for the sleep_time column in the notepad file is showing this:`vcc,device_id,temp,hum,packet_no,sleep_time

3776,0EE3C60C,26.12,62.31,3,"5}
"

3853,0BD776ED,24.40,65.19,4,"3}
"

3776,0EE3C60C,26.03,63.61,4,"5}
"

3853,0BD776ED,24.43,65.37,5,"3}
"

`

Comment: the "3} " inverted commas are hiding the data from being displayed in the excel file and in the notepad file the data can be viewed but with the inverted commas

Comment: @RuchiIsaac It looks as though your input data isn't exactly the way you described it in your question. I did say at the outset you needed to be sure you know *exactly* what the noise will be. I suspect your data has a trailing space after the `}`. Amend the `strip()` call as I have shown in the amended question to deal with this.

Comment: My data is of around 2000 lines and this code is not working for multiple lines. Also, the only thing apart from the noise after the "}" is a '\n' not literally but figuratively since the next row of data is displayed in the next line.

Comment: By multiple lines i mean that it's not working for 2000 line and is showing the following error: `ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required`

Comment: Can I suggest that you list the intermediate results `rows` and `dictrows`, as I did in the answer, and show the intermediate result that corresponds to the error message. The code works with the data you presented, so there must be something different about the other data.

Comment: And `dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1` is because you have text between 2 `&` signs with no `=` in between. That also was not in your description of the data. Again, present the data that results in the error message, not just the error message.

Comment: I solved it with the help of your suggestions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your data is formatted very much like url parameters, so you can use the `urllib` module to parse that data into a `dict`.

Also, the `strip` method on strings can be used to strip all unwelcome characters at once, from the edges of the string.

This example should make it clear:

```
import urllib.parse

s1 = 'ÿ{device_id=0BD776ED&temp=24.40&hum=65.19&vcc=3853&packet_no=4&sleep_time=3}' 
s2 = 'þ{device_id=0BD776ED&temp=24.15&hum=65.27&vcc=3853&packet_no=6&sleep_time=3}' 
s3 = 'ü{device_id=0BD776ED&temp=23.81&hum=61.76&vcc=3827&packet_no=45&sleep_time=3}' 
s4 = '{device_id=0BD776ED&temp=22.46&hum=61.62&vcc=3840&packet_no=38&sleep_time=3}'

parameters = s1.strip('ÿþü{}')
result = urllib.parse.parse_qs(parameters)

# result - {'device_id': ['0BD776ED'], 'temp': ['24.40'], 'hum': ['65.19'], 'vcc': ['3853'], 'packet_no': ['4'], 'sleep_time': ['3']}
```

This example only parses `s1` but you can test it and see that it also parses all the other strings as well. Notice that the results of each key are lists, you may wish to "flatten" them later.

In any case, your syntax is the  main problem here, that is not at all python syntax. You should learn the basic syntax on if...else commands in python and move up from there, from the bottom up. See here: http://tutorialspoint.com/python/python_if_else.htm

Answer (score 0):

From what I can Understand is that you need data to be extracted in-order to write it into a csv file.

```
    #this is your Sample DATA
    sample_data='ÿ{device_id=0BD776ED&temp=24.40&hum=65.19&vcc=3853&packet_no=4&sleep_time=3}'
```

## remove all noise before the 1st '{'

```
    `temp_sample=sample.split('{')[1]'
```

## remove all the noise after '}'

```
    `temp_sample=temp_sample.split('}')`
```

## split using '&'

```
    `temp_sample=temp_sample[0].split('&')`
```

## Output:

```
    `print temp_sample`
```

For Exporting it into a csv file you can use Dictionary Writer in python!!